# Android Kotlin Kotlinx Module Level View Binding

Tags: android, binding, kotlin, kotlin-extension

I am trying to bind views from another module layout with kotlin extention. There is no problem if the layout in the same module that I'm working currently. But if I use a layout from another module and what if I want to bind that layout with kotlinx? I'm currently getting "unresolved reference: kotlinx" error. So briefly how to bind module level views with kotlinx? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is not supported yet. This unexpected behavior is described on [KT-22430 ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-22430). The work to make it available is in progress and it is expected to work on Kotlin 1.2.60.